# HTML PHP html php redirect same page with additional message

Tags: php, html, forms

I am creating a submit contact form. However when the submit button is pressed, i want it to go back to my contact.php page with an additional message at the top of the body page such as.
"We have received your email, our agent will contact you shortly"

i have two files, contact.php for form and send_form_email.php for email process

i have tried this

```
header("location: contact.php");
```

however this would only send me back to contact page without any confirmation

Can you please kindly help me ?

Regards,
Lex

Comment: You can use [**sessions**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) but you need to be careful on how you use it. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In file `Contact.php` add

```
$done = $_GET['done'];
if ($done == 1){
    echo "<div>We have received your email, our agent will contact you shortly</div>";
}
```

In file `send_form_email.php` add

```
header("Location: contact.php?done=1");
```

Comment: Location HTTP header must contain absolute URL. Not sure what PHP and Apache do with this… In CGI script this should issue internal redirect, but that will not work under mod_php, IMO. If it works and an absolute URL is sent in the header, PHP does some magic – beware, it could be broken!

Comment: @Palec valid point but PHP/Apache has (arguably wrongly) never given a damn despite the fact that the `header()` function is supposed to send a raw HTTP header and even the PHP documentation states to use absolute URLs.

Comment: @CD001 I always read the specs and docs, staying on the safe side. When I learn more about the quirks of PHP, such as this one, I tend to bang my head against the wall or laugh uncontrollably. Anyway, good to know that this works. Thanks for confirmation.

Comment: @Palec I knew that right when I sent the edit but there is no way to undo it when it is sent.  The problem was that I sent my edit almost exactly at the same time you made yours.  Therefore, the edit message didn't even show up and tell me that someone else had made an edit.  After that, I could neither revert nor unsend the edit.

Comment: @Anonymous That’s OK. Everything explained and put in order now. I reverted your edit. The simple version control implemented here cannot handle edit conflicts and it cannot be seen on which version you based your edit.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do it is a query string.

```
header("location: contact.php?success=1");
```

Or something like that.

Then in your contact page, you check for that using `$_GET['success']` and if it is set (you can use `isset()` to just see if its in the URL or check the actual value if you want to do more) display your message.

For something slightly more "complex", see this: [PHP passing messages between pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425178/php-passing-messages-between-pages)

Comment: It's not a big deal,but that means I can enter that url and see the message all the time.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using POST in your form. Using GET in this is a bad idea.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Then add

```
if($_POST["done"] == 1)
   echo "We have received your email, our agent will contact you shortly";
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple options.

The simplest would be to just have the form processing logic on the same page and then set your form's action attribute to that page.

You could do something like checking if you have a value posted to tell you if you need to process the page.

```
if (isset($_POST['my_value_from_form'])) {
    // process
}

// body of page itself
```

That lets you put one pretty easily.

Another way would be to add a GET value by appending it to the URL:

```
header("location: contact.php?message=1")
```

And use that with `$_GET['message']` to determine what to show. However, that ?message=1 will be in the URL of the page, so it may not be ideal.

The other way would be to set a session value before you direct, then check if that value is there (and also clear it after you display it.

```
// on send_form_email.php
session_start();
$_SESSION['message'] = 1;

// on contact.php
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['message'] == 1) {
    // do something
}

unset($_SESSION['message']); // so it only shows once.
```

All ways have minor trade-offs, mostly just owing to how you organize your code. If I was going to implement it, I would use the session method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [**sessions**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) for that. Example

```
session_start(); // start session
$_SESSION['message'] = 'We have received your email, our agent will contact you shortly';
header("location: contact.php");
```

In your `contact.php`

```
echo $_SESSION['message']; 
unset($_SESSION['message']); // delete message so it doesnt display again
```

Answer (score 0):

change your header to

```
header("location: contact.php?success");
```

and then on your `contact.php` add this at the top of your page

```
if(isset($_GET['success'])){
    echo "We have received your email, our agent will contact you shortly";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make a session of message like this

```
  $_SESSION['message'] = "your message";
```

and after that you do redirect insert this session inside message div and then unset it

```
<?php

 session_start();

 $_SESSION['message'] = "your message";
 header("location: contact.php");
```

dont forget to start the session with `session_start();`  on top of your file contact.php